# How to assign a value to a column by using String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method like this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def assign_weighted_values
    unless foo.nil?
      self.weighted_foo = 3 * foo
    end
    unless bar.nil?
      self.weighted_bar = 3 * bar
    end
    unless hoge.nil?
      self.weighted_hoge = 3 * hoge
    end
  end
end
```

But I want to write this like:

```
  def assign_weighted_values
    %w(foo bar hoge).each do |column|
      next if send(column).nil?
      self.send("weighted_#{column}") = 3 * column
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to assign a value to column by using String?

Comment: A few typos aside, your code already does this - what more do you want?

Comment: @FrederickCheung my code end up with `syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end`

Comment: that is happening because you are setting the "getter" method for your attributes. self.send("weighted_#{column}") will simply fetch the value of that attribute. so the equal sign in front of that is throwing an error. What you need to do is call the "setter" method. Like this, self.send("weighted_#{column}=", "value-you-want-to-set")

Comment: Thanks, I didn't aware the ActiveRecord::Base Model have setter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes)

```
def assign_weighted_values
  %(foo bar hoge).each do |column|
    next if send(column).nil?
    assign_attributes({ "weighted_#{column}" => 3 * column })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def assign_weighted_values
  %w(foo bar hoge).each do |column|
   next if send(column).nil?
   self.send("weighted_#{column}=",3 * column)
  end
 self.save
 end
```